# Javascript method not working in BabylonJS with a custom Mesh

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

I'm very new to BabylonJS and I created a custom Mesh like that (I don't know if it's the right way) :

```
function DragSphere() {
    this.sphere = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateSphere("sphere", 15, 2, scene);
    this.sphere.material = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial("sphereMat", scene);
    ...
    return (this.sphere);
}

DragSphere.prototype.setRGBColor = function(r, g, b) {
    this.sphere.material.diffuseColor = new BABYLON.Color3(r/255, g/255, b/255);
}
```

So I want to use the `SetRGBColor` method of my `DragSphere` to update its color, but the browser does not seems to agree with me :

```
 Uncaught TypeError: sphere.setRGBColor is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `return (this.sphere);` statement from the constructor.

If you're using TypeScript only a void function can be called with the `new` operator. Calling the function with a return type in its signature, as above, will result in the `setRGBColor` function being undefined in the transpiled JavaScript.

You can try this out in the [Babylon JS playground](http://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#).

Comment: Ok - the same applies to JavaScript (although I don't think you  always get the error message for returning in the constructor). Have you tried removing the return statement? @boehm_s

Comment: I'll try this WE because my project is on another computer, thank you ;)

Comment: Great - let me know how it goes!

Comment: Wheres the playground?